# Black or purple screen instead of log in

Tags: boot, server, nvidia, xorg, login-screen

### Ubuntu 16.04 boots to a black screen.

**I'm using nvidia gtx 580**, and it was running smoothly before something happened.

---

- When I open tty7:

  ```
  /dev/sda1: clean, blahblah/blahblah files, blahblah/blahblah blocks.
  ```
- There is `webmin` and `teamviewer` installed. When I access this machine from `teamviewer`, I can see the log in screen, but when I try to log in, it kicks me out of `teamviewer` after a few seconds. Even with monitor attached.
- I reinstalled and tried different video drivers. Now it boots to a purple screen instead. I still have access to tty.
- I uninstalled `teamviewer`, and that did not help either.
- I can confirm that everything else is working, because I have full access to `webmin` and `tty`, all files and servers are running as they should. Maybe I messed it up when trying to install a fake monitor? I tried reinstalling `xorg` along with `ubuntu-desktop` completely.
- When I run `shutdown` from `webmin` or `tty`, I can see the purple screen with UBUNTU logo and animated orange dots, while it's shutting down.

It's hard for me to say when exactly this happened. Probably it could happen when either I messed up with `xorg` files trying to install a fake monitor for `teamviewer` or when I ran an update for all installed apps from `webmin`.

I know I could do a fresh install of Ubuntu but that would be my last option.

---

**Tried solutions:**

- Reinstalling Xorg
- Reinstalling nvidia drivers, version 364, latest version, and system76 drivers, none helps. The only difference is that the screen is either black or purple.
- Reinstalling ubuntu desktop

---

**UPDATES:**

When I tried to run sudo gedit /etc/default/grub I got an error:

```
gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

Reinstalled drivers again, and when I try to run `X -configure` I get an error: `No devices to configure`, I DO have nvidia in List of video drivers.

I changed video card from GTX 580 to 7800 GTX (yeah, the very old one), no changes.

Ubuntu from live cd works with UI, without any problem on any of those cards.

There is no xorg.conf file created neither in my ubuntu installation, nor on live-cd version.

---

Please, help! Thanks for your time!

Comment: I specifically mentioned, that I checked other similar questions, and I need a more targeted help. I believe that this is a very broad problem, with a lot of variables, and I would really benefit from someone experienced helping me out, taking into account all the mentioned details.

Comment: I also mentioned that I tried reinstalling xorg, nvidia drivers and ubuntu desktop, as suggested in the given link, and none of that helped. Maybe i'm doing something wrong. (could not edit my previous comment)

Answer (score 0):

Finally.

The problem solved simply by removing `xorg.conf` file, however it was not located under `/etc/X11` folder, as most answers in the link suggested by M. Becerra point to, but it was located under `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/xorg.conf`.

Removed\purged nvidia drivers completely, removed `xorg.conf` from live CD (could use tty as well), and now it works.

I was confused by the fact that most answers said that `xorg.conf` should be under `etc/X11`, probably outdated information.

I don't have enough reputation to comment those answers, please, someone, update information in here: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

And yes, it was my own mistake, because I broke xorg.conf file while trying to add dummy monitor for teamviewer access.

Ok, wait, it does not work completley, now it seems to be in login loop mentioned there... trying to solve that problem now...

Ok, now my broke something else trying to run ubuntu-drivers autoinstall, or whatever the command is, and no I got nothing, no tty, no login screen, just the black screen with cursor, and some commands running when I plug usb drive in or out. All servers still work in the background.

frak this, Ill just reinstall it.